# Formatting JSON for email body

Tags: javascript, json, regex, pretty-print

I've JSON in the following format that I'm trying to insert into outlook/email client's body using

```
location.href = "mailto:" + "email@domain.com" + "?subject=" + "Notes" + "&body=" + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
```

Giving 4 spaces `JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)`

```
[
    {
        "page": "article_0_page_0",
        "note": "Note 1"
    },
    {
        "page": "article_0_page_1",
        "note": "Note 2"
    }
]
```

I want to output as

```
<b>article_0_page_0</b>\n\r
Note 1

<b>article_0_page_1</b>\n\r
Note 2
```

Any regular expression solution please.

Edit: My attempt

```
var str = "";
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            str += "<strong>" + data[i].page + "</strong><br>" + data[i].note + "<br><br>";
        }
```

Comment: Could you please describe what you have tried?

Comment: Could you provide us with what you've done so far?

Comment: @k0pernikus You got me with 11 seconds :)

Comment: @Oleander It would have been even faster, but for some reason "What did you try?" is no allowed content for a comment ;)

Comment: edited with my non regular expression based attempt

Comment: @user2727195 Why not just change it according to your specs? You're almost done.

Comment: This is a valid question with a valid answer, it does not deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here ya go

```
var json = [
    {
        "page": "article_0_page_0",
        "note": "Note 1"
    },
    {
        "page": "article_0_page_1",
        "note": "Note 2"
    }
];

var out = "";

for (var key in json) {
  if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      out += "<b>"+json[key].page+"</b>\r\n"+json[key].note+"\r\n\r\n";
  }
}

console.log(out);
```

Example Here: https://jsfiddle.net/q5r4gdcn/1/

Comment: please explain why json.hasOwnProperty

Comment: hasOwnProperty() is a method for checking if the inspected property belongs to the object. See this link for details: http://brianflove.com/2013/09/05/javascripts-hasownproperty-method/

Comment: but JSON objects always have property of it's own, wondering when is the case when JSON object doesn't have a property of it's own

Comment: You could instantiate 2 instances of "Object" and added property3 to "ObjectA" and none to ObjectB. These would be two instances of the same Object but ObjectA now has been extended to have property3 and ObjectB does not. Why? A billion reasons come up during programming, you just have to come by them on your journey to guru level.

Answer (score 10):

I think the above answer is ok if you have a flat structure.

If you want a more holistic approach for email specifically, I have found this to work really well.

```
const data = {...}
JSON.stringify( data, null, '&nbsp;' ).split( '\n' ).join( '<br>' );
```

This will convert something like this

```
const json = {
  "status": "ok",
   "config": {
     "gotIt": "yes",
     "transform": [
       null
     ]
   }
}
```

Into something like this

```
{<br>&nbsp"status": "ok",<br>&nbsp"config": {<br>&nbsp&nbsp"gotIt": "yes",<br>&nbsp&nbsp"transform": [<br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspnull<br>&nbsp&nbsp]<br>&nbsp}<br>}
```

Email clients will render this as the following

```
{
 "status": "ok",
 "config": {
  "gotIt": "yes",
  "transform": [
   null
  ]
 }
}
```

This is done by using the additional parameters in `JSON.stringify` which I don't see used very often if you want to read more about these parameters here is the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Syntax) for them.

Comment: How did you got the email client to render like in the last example?? I run the code and got somthing like this - which is not helpful at all: "{<br>&nbsp"status": "ok",<br>&nbsp"config": {<br>&nbsp&nbsp"gotIt": "yes",<br>&nbsp&nbsp"transform": [<br>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspnull<br>&nbsp&nbsp]<br>&nbsp}<br>}"

Comment: I did get it to render. Make sure the client allows html by send it an html email you know works. If that does make sure you are sending an html email not just text.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to convert basic JSON to "readable" for email:

```js
let json = {
  "key": "asdas",
  "query": "",
  "hints": {
    "nested1": "blahblah"
  }
}

let prettyJSON = JSON.stringify(json, null, '&nbsp;')
  .split('\n')
  .join('<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;')
  .split('<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;}').join('<br>}')

document.body.innerHTML += `<div>${prettyJSON}</div>`
```